# ¿Cómo regenerar la BD en ASP.NET MVC usando el enfoque Code First?

Tags: base-de-datos, asp.net-mvc, code-first

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación con ASP.NET MVC usando Visual Studio 2015 aplicando el enfoque Code First. Es decir, a partir del modelo de clases genero la base de datos.

Todo me funcionó correctamente. El problema es que ahora quiero cambiar el tipo de dato de uno de los atributos de una clase del modelo.

¿Cómo hago para regenerar la base de datos con el nuevo cambio en el modelo sin tener que volver a generar todo el proyecto?

Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Encontré que la solución es utilizar "Entity Framework Code First Migrations".

Documentación aquí:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx

Comment: De ese enlace, extrae un ejemplo que cumpla con lo que estás buscando, de tal manera si el enlace se rompe, queda la información en el sitio. Saludos